# Visible Data on WPF DataGrid in MVVM

Tags: wpf, optimization, mvvm, datagrid

Is there any way to know which data objects are visible on WPF DataGrid when working in MVVM? The DataGrid that I have binded with object model has many filter operations and shows only filtered data depending upon selected filter. I have to solve an optimization problem. A brief description of problem is described here.

During remote communication, I am sending ALL the data binded to DataGrid through GSM modem to remote device. Because most of the time I have too much data binded to DataGrid (Even after selecting specific filter), I was looking to send only data that is currently visible to optimize communication.

I can explain if someone needs more detail.

Here is how DataGrid is binded with Items Source in WPF.

```
        <toolkitControls:AdvancedDataGrid x:Name="RecordEditorTable"
                                      Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                      Style="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                      SelectionMode="Extended"
                                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredRecords}"
                                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                      cal:Message.Attach="[BeginningEdit] =  [BeginningEditing($eventArgs)]; [RowEditEnding] = [RowEditEnding($eventArgs)]; [SelectionChanged] = [RecordEditorTable_SelectionChanged($eventArgs)]; 
                                      AllowDrop="True">...</toolkitControls:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sample code please. ?

Comment: I have added WPF code for DataGrid, FilteredRecords is an ObservableCollection of Record Items.

Comment: Which Thirdparty DataGrid is this ?

Comment: Its my own customized DataGrid, I just added some small functions (nothing much importent) in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an idea to the problem. I will use LoadingRow and UnloadingRow events and from the loaded rows, I can get the data to send to remote device. These events will be fired only on scrolling the datagrid, so I can remove invisible data from communication layer and register newly visible data for communication. 
The events do not get fired on DataGrid population, so I have to manage this special scenerio.

Some more ideas for those interested are [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00348ef6-05aa-4a47-b8ca-3ffa77ca2449/get-visible-rows-from-wpf-datagrid-in-mvvm?prof=required).